# How can I enable wpa_supplicant on boot?

Tags: fedora, systemd, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to enable wpa_supplicant on boot in Fedora 20. I created `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and am able to connect to my wireless network manually by running

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -Dwext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

(I can confirm that I'm connected by running `iwconfig`)

I'm brand new to systemd and can't figure out how to get this to happen on boot. I've found guides for other distros that use systemd that say all you need to do is

```
systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0
```

but when I run that command, I get

```
Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
```

---

*Note: [cross-posted](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/59278/how-can-i-enable-wpa_supplicant-on-boot/) on the official Fedora support forums, but haven't received any answers yet.*

Comment: What is the content of the systemd unit that you created? And where are these "guides for other distros that use systemd"? I hardly think is all they say

Comment: Are you positive you have a `wlan0`?  Fedora doesn't use that naming scheme for network interfaces.

Comment: @Braiam I didn't create a systemd unit. According to the [Arch Linux wiki on wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#At_boot_.28systemd.29), "The `wpa_supplicant` package provides multiple systemd service files: `wpa_supplicant.service` [...] `wpa_supplicant@.service` - accepts the interface name as an argument and starts the `wpa_supplicant` daemon for this interface. It reads the configuration file in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-interface.conf`. [...]" It seems you don't get all of these on Fedora.

Comment: Are you sure those exist in Fedora? If they don't you may need to create them [like this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Manual_wireless_connection_at_boot_using_systemd_and_dhcpcd)

Comment: The only one I see in `systemctl list-units --all` is `wpa_supplicant.service`, so I guess I'll have to create `wpa_supplicant@.service`. Not sure how I missed the page you linked to...that looks like exactly what I need, thank you. I'll give that a try later today.

Comment: @Braiam I had to make some tweaks to get it to work on my system (see my answer below), but the link you provided was very helpful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Braiam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/41104/braiam) suggested in the comments that if `wpa_supplicant@wlan0` doesn't exist, I may need to create it myself, and also pointed me to a page in the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Manual_wireless_connection_at_boot_using_systemd_and_dhcpcd) describing how to do so. I had to tweak things slightly for Fedora, but the following worked for me:

1. Create a systemd unit, `/etc/systemd/system/network-wireless@.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Wireless network connectivity (%i)
   Wants=network.target
   Before=network.target
   BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
   After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   RemainAfterExit=yes

   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ip link set dev %i up
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -i %i -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
   #ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhclient %i

   ExecStop=/usr/sbin/ip link set dev %i down

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   Note that I had to change the paths to `ip` and `wpa_supplicant` from `/usr/bin/` to `/usr/sbin/` for my system. I also changed `dhcpcd` to `dhclient`, since I don't have `dhcpcd` installed.
2. Create a symbolic link in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`:

   ```
   ln -s /etc/systemd/system/network-wireless@.service \
     /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/network-wireless@wlan0.service
   ```

   I had to do this because running

   ```
   systemctl enable network-wireless@wlan0.service
   ```

   as described in the Arch Linux wiki failed with

   ```
   Failed to issue method call: No such file or directory
   ```
3. Start the service:

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   systemctl start network-wireless@wlan0.service
   ```

---

Now I'm able to connect to my wireless network on boot. I haven't figured out how to configure DHCP properly (hence the `dhclient` line being commented out in my systemd unit), but that's a different question.

Comment: Did you ever get DHCP working?

Comment: @JasonKelley I think so but it's been so long that I honestly don't remember, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it returns the error "Failure to issue method call:.." because it cannot find the wlan0 interface. Are you sure that your wireless card is actually referred to as wlan0. Fedora introduced a new naming scheme with version 15, deviating from the usual ethX/wlanX naming for network devices: More specific information can be found in the [wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ConsistentNetworkDeviceNaming)

Type the following commands in a shell to find the name of the wireless card (sample output shown below)

```
$ ifconfig
$ iwconfig

Sample outputs

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
lo        no wireless extensions.
p1p1      no wireless extensions.
```

here the wirelesscard is called wlp1s0

Comment: `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` both show `wlan0`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot glad you were able to solve the problem